# jquery-ui - on jquery(MySelctor).draggable , from callback function , how to loop on each element of MySelector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

using :

jQuery(MySelector).dragabble (  start: function( e, ui ) {  } )

on start function :
the start event gives $(this) that drag the current dragged element from MySelector, that is correct.

how to loop on each element in MySelector,
so I can make additional code to treat these other elements.
actutally I ask, what is the object name inside the function( e, ui ) 
I can get a list of elements of MySelector ?,
so I can loop on the list.

if I use className it 'remembers' of course all the elements that are not in the current 'MySelector'

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you want, but I assume you want to get all child DOM elements of the current MySelector DOM element, when the draggable action starts.

Simply use `this`. But because `this` may also be a child of `MySelector`, you'll first need to get the closests `MySelector` element. This element will be `this`'s parent element. Like this:

```
jquery(MySelector).dragabble({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        var parent = this.closest(MySelector);
        var children = parent.children;

        ...
    } 
});
```

For iteration, you need to create an array of this list, using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
    ...

    Array.from(children).forEach((child) => {
        console.log(child);
    });

    ...
```

Of course you can shorten the code to an one-liner or use jQuery for the same effect. I like to use plain javascript.

Comment: there is no this this.childern I checked with chrome devtools it gives: this.children
HTMLCollection []length: 0__proto__: HTMLCollection , ==> means no elements under this,

Comment: Then apparently,  the element which gets dragged, doesn't contain any other HTML elements. Try posting some more code about what your HTML looks like and what value MySelector is supposed to be. And maybe clarify more what you mean with "each element in MySelector".

Comment: MySelector may be '.drag' or '#id1 #id2 #id3', from function(e,ui) I want to loop(itterate) on these generated list by jquery . in .draggable event i get only the actual mouse down clicked element $(this) , I think I am very clear

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now more. Looks like the clicked element is a child element of MySelector, so you need to get this elements parent. I'll update the answer.

Comment: this.closest(MySelector);, gave the current dragged id, and parent.children - cause undefined, I wonder now just make again jQuery(Myselector).each inside the function ?, but anyway, thanks for your help @Sample777

Answer (score 0):

Use each by children

```
$(MySelector).children().each(function () {
   //Your Code 
}
```

> **.children( [selector ] )**
>
> **Type:** Selector
>
> A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.

Comment: you did not give the syntax of jQuery(MySelector).draggable(...) , where is coming the .each  inside the function(e,ui) ?

Comment: so actually you suggest to make another jQuery(MySelector) inside the function, and not use some generated array that jquery can suggest from MySelector ?